# Webshot a plotly plot from R shiny full page, or without white space

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, plotly, export-to-pdf

**How to save a plot to pdf without lots of white space margin, full page size no matter what?**

I have tried to modify my code below but I can't get it to work as needed. 
I looked into adding a selector argument, but that throws errors no matter what target object I use, probably because this code is actually webshotting the temp.html file??

using this alternative:

```
 export(values$p, file = 'exportplot.pdf')
```

also creates the enormous white space around the plot.

I have spend a few hours playing with size arguments of both the plot, and the export codes,  but that only seems to mess up the ratio between plot size and plot font size.

**My current solution works, but not 100%** using webshot

What I have now it this dummy app that saves the plots in PDF format! Great, amazing quality as the image is a vector. 
However, I end up with a lot of white space and a 2nd blanc page in the pdfs 
Some tweaking by adding zoom = 0.6 fixes this a little bit, but I have a feeling there is a better solution.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    mainPanel(
     plotlyOutput('prlotly'),
     actionButton(inputId = 'Saveplot', label = icon('floppy-o'), style = "height:40px; width:40px; border-radius: 6px; border-width:3px; border-color:#339fff; 
              color: #339fff; background-color:#fff; font-size:1.4em; padding:0px")
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues()
  output$prlotly <- renderPlotly({ p <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~cyl, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
    values$p <- p
})


 observeEvent(input$Saveplot, {
   if (!require("webshot")) install.packages("webshot")
   saveWidget(as_widget(values$p), "temp.html")
     webshot("temp.html", file = "widgettoplot10.pdf", zoom = 0.6)
  }, ignoreInit = T)
 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```